# Moving Spark DataFrame from Python to Scala whithn Zeppelin

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I created a spark DataFrame in a Python paragraph in Zeppelin.

```py
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
spDf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)
```

and `df` is a pandas dataframe

```py
print(type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

what I want to do is moving `spDf` from one Python paragraph to another Scala paragraph. It look a reasonable way to do is using `z.put`.

```py
z.put("spDf", spDf)
```

and I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Any suggestion to fix the error? Or any suggestion to move `spDf`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can`put` internal Java object not a Python wrapper:

```py
%pyspark

df = sc.parallelize([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")]).toDF(["k", "v"])
z.put("df", df._jdf)
```

and then make sure you use correct type:

```scala
val df = z.get("df").asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: bigint, v: string]
```

but it is better to register temporary table:

```py
%pyspark

# registerTempTable in Spark 1.x
df.createTempView("df")
```

and use [`SQLContext.table`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L826) to read it:

```scala
// sqlContext.table in Spark 1.x
val df = spark.table("df")
```

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: bigint, v: string]
```

To convert in the opposite direction see [Zeppelin: Scala Dataframe to python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35719142/1560062)