# Pyspark Jupyter - dataframe created in java code vs python code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, py4j

I have a class in java that builds some sophisticated Spark DataFrame.

```
package companyX;

class DFBuilder {
   public DataFrame build() {
       ...
       return dataframe;
   }
}
```

I add this class to the pyspark/jupiter classpath so its callable by py4j.
Now when I call it I get strange type:

```
b = sc._jvm.companyX.DFBuilder()
print(type(b.build()))
#prints: py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject
```

VS

```
print(type(sc.parallelize([]).toDF()))
#prints: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

Is there a way to convert this JavaObject into proper pyspark dataframe?
One of the problems I have is that when I want to call df.show() on a DataFrame build in java is that it gets printed in spark logs, and not in notebook cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` initializer:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

DataFrame(b.build(), spark)
```

If you use outdated Spark version replace `SparkSession` instance with `SQLContext`.

Refference [Zeppelin: Scala Dataframe to python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35719142)

Answer (score 2):

As of spark 2.4 you still should be using `SQLContext` instead of `SparkSession` when wrapping scala dataframe in python one. 
Some relevant `pyspark` `session` code:

```
self._wrapped = SQLContext(self._sc, self, self._jwrapped)
...
# in methods returning DataFrame
return DataFrame(jdf, self._wrapped)
```

If `SparkSession` gets passed some methods like `toPandas()` won't work with such `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

For someone with sparkSession object, even with newer spark (like 3.2)

```
# sparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
    .appName('sample') \
    .getOrCreate()

# py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject
javaOjbectDf= spark._jvm.com.your.javaPackage.DfBuilder()

sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext=spark.sparkContext, sparkSession=spark)
df_from_java = DataFrame(javaOjbectDf, sqlContext)

# python DataFrame
print(df_from_java)
```