# How to bring Scala DataFrame to Python and vice versa without registering a view?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a library written in Scala that has some functions for loading data from a number of measuring data formats and doing some calculations. These functions all operate on the Scala version of the `DataFrame`.

I now want to use these libraries in Python code with PySpark. I wrote some helper objects (since my library uses a lot of implicits in package objects) to aid calling the stuff from Python, and I succeed with something like this: (`spark` is the Python `SparkSession`)

```
sdf = spark._jvm.com.mycompany.PyApiFooHelper.loadFooMeasuringData(spark._jsparkSession, "hdfs:///some/where")
sCalcResult = spark._jvm.com.mycompany.PyApiBarCalculationHelper.doBarCalculation(sdf)
```

When I want `sCalcResult` in Python, I currently do it as outlined in [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719142/zeppelin-scala-dataframe-to-python) registering a temporary view and bringing that in:

```
sCalcResult.createOrReplaceTempView("sCalcResult")
calcResult = spark._wrapped.table("sCalcResult")
```

However I find that ugly, because it can lead to name clashes when "hiding that away" for my fellow data scientists because the functions need to create temporary tables every time. Or I generate random table names but then I might have tons of tables lying around that are not needed any more after a time.

So, is there a function like:

```
pythonDataFrame = scalaToPythonDataframe(scalaDataFrame)
```

The Python DFs have a `_jdf` field to get the Java/Scala DF, so kludging around using a temporary view cannot be the way... Or is it?

EDIT: I am currently using Spark 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at Spark's source code and found the solution.

A `DataFrame` has a two-argument constructor that takes a JVM DF reference and an `SQLContext`, in its Python variant.

The `SQLContext` is obtained from the `SparkSession` via its `_wrapped` field or from another `DataFrame` via its `sql_ctx` field.

So, it is done like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Use Spark DataSource API instead of explicit method
df = spark.read.format("com.mycompany.formats.foo").load("hdfs:///some/where")
sCalcResult = spark._jvm.com.mycompany.PyApiBarCalculationHelper.doBarCalculation(df._jdf)
barCalcResult = DataFrame(sCalcResult, spark._wrapped)
```